# What is this weird little bump on my tomato?

Tags: tomatoes, growth

So I picked this lovely brandywine tomato yesterday and noticed this extra little bumpy thing.  What is it?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon is commonly known as [tomato nose](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=tomato%20noses&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=tomato%20noses&sc=3-12&cvid=46D62799A49A44AAA98781FD724EEBF5&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&first=1&tsc=ImageHoverTitle)

Some experts says it is related to cold weather and pollination, others says [too high temperatures](https://homegardenjoy.com/site/2016/09/causes-tomato-nose.html):

> What is so interesting to me is that extended high temperatures over
> 90 degrees, particularly warm evening temperatures, can increase the
> likelihood of the deformity.

[This site](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/tomato/weird-shaped-tomatoes.htm) suggests it "happens more often with older heirloom varieties", which includes brandywine tomatoes.

Comment: Fascinating!  A brief look on Google images  revealed that instead of eating this specimen I should have gotten creative with googly eyes!